# Corona transition.moveTo() seems to stop other transitions on the same object?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-engine

```
local rect = display.newRoundedRect(200, 200, 150, 150, 2)
rect.fill = {0,0,0}
rect.alpha = 0.1
rect.xScale = 0.1
rect.yScale = 0.1
transition.to(rect, {time=1000, xScale=1, yScale=1, alpha=1}) -- transA

local function moveListener()
      transition.moveTo(rect, {time=800,x=300, y=300}) -- this will puase transA!!
end

timer.performWithDelay(400,moveListener, 1)
```

Any idea how to perform moveTo() without stopping other transitions?

Cheers!

Comment: You should NOT use more than 1 transition to change ONE object properties, think this: `transA = transition.to(rect, {time=800,x=300, y=300})` & `transB = transition.to(rect, {delay=100,time=800,x=0, y=100})` ,how the `rect` doing after 100ms later?

Comment: I beleive it is OK to perform 2 transactions at a time. In my case, transA is just scaling the object and the other transition is to move it.

Comment: But this is a bad habits; You can use `transition.moveTo(rect, { delay = 400, time = 800, x = 300, y = 300 })` instead of `timer. performWithDelay (400,XXX)`

Comment: Ok this may be a better practice, but the issue is still exist.

Comment: I tried `transition.moveTo(rect, { delay = 400, time = 800, x = 300, y = 300 })`   the issue is not exist…… I used Corona Simulator 2015.2731

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on my computer, and it seems to be an issue with `transition.moveTo()`.

It works using `transition.to()`.

Comment: Yah, I already tried it, My point is as I noticed, moving objects using `transition.moveTo()` is smoother than `transition.to()`.

Comment: Strange. As the Corona SDK docs state, these are only **shortcuts** and shouldn't affect performance. https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/media/transitionLib/index.html#convenience

Answer (score -1):

I just tried the following:

```
 local rect1 = display.newRoundedRect(100, 100, 150, 150, 2)
  rect1.fill = {0,0,0}

  local rect2 = display.newRoundedRect(300, 100, 150, 150, 2)
  rect2.fill = {1,0,1}

  transition.moveTo(rect1, {time=1000, y=500})
  transition.to(rect2, {time=1000, y=500})
```

And noticed that rect1 moved after rect2 with some delay!. However,  adding small delay to `transition.to()`  will make the movement exactly identical as follows:
`transition.to(rect2, {delay=1, time=1000, y=500})`

To summerize, it is still an issue with `moveTo()` to stop other transitions. As work around, in order to get exact behavior just use `transition.to()` with micro delay as previous line of code!

Thanks.....